# Example of an iPhone app which uses long press option

Tags: iphone

I need an example of an iPhone application that uses the long press option.

Please, show me just one, :), and I'd like it to be free

Best regards

Comment: `UILongPressGestureRecogniser` is what you're looking for if you want to implement it yourself...

Comment: Just to add to David's comment, here is [Apple's official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `UILongPressGestureRecogniser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Springboard, the built-in shell application that launches all of the other applications is a perfect example.

When a long press is registered on any app icon, all of the icons start shaking to indicate that it is in editing mode.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps - Long press an area and it drops a pin at that location.

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to your class .h file with type UILongPressGestureRecognizer.
Like this:

```
@interface test_for_stackoverflowAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
{  
     UIWindow *window;    
     UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr;    
}
```

Then add this to your .m file:

```
lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress)];                 
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
[self.window addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```

And this function:

```
-(void) handleLongPress{
    if (lpgr.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
         NSLog(@"Long Press detected!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the ivar if the window owns it, you can accept the gesture recognizer instance in the action method.

Comment: thx for your answer, I just neen an app, no code